# Locomotive CMS with Rails - location for liquid templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locomotivecms

I'm new to both Ruby on Rails and Locomotive CMS, but I'm just starting to create my first site with them.

I've got the engine running in a full Rails app (I'm going to need to deploy it on our own server later on). But it's just spitting out the 'Template' content defined through the admin interface, without any other template/content around it.

[image: admin screen]

[image]

I can 'fix' it by shoving the html for the whole page in through this input field. But that's not right, surely? The Getting Started guide talks of putting the templates in the filesystem, at something like: Pages/index/first page. "All pages are inherited from index". I have an index.liquid under views/pages but it's not picking that up... (I've tried a couple of other locations too).

I'm sure this is a dumb question, but please could someone tell me where to put my template in the file system? Or how to point Locomotive to pick it up from the right place?

(I did get the file system liquid template working by defining it through the Rails way, with a route, a controller and adding a liquid template initializer I found [here](http://royvandermeij.com/blog/2011/09/21/create-a-liquid-handler-for-rails-3-dot-1/). But then it's missing the variables that should come from the CMS content).

I'm loading the site using `bundle exec unicorn_rails`. And I'm using Rails v3.2.13, Ruby v1.9.3 and Locomotive_cms v2.2.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm Didier from LocomotiveCMS.

LocomotiveCMS is a little bit different from the other CMS, in a sense, we offer a tool named Wagon to manage your site locally without having to install mongodb, rails and some other components. 
Another huge benefit is that you can write your templates in HAML and your CSS in SASS/ SCSS or Less (we embedded Compass as well) and with our preferred texts editor (editing a whole site in a browser is a nightmare).
That's a nice eco-system in order to be super efficient when it comes to develop a LocomotiveCMS site.

Once you're done with your local work, you can deploy your site to a remote LocomotiveCMS engine in a similar way you push your application to Heroku. Actually, pushing a site will create the back-office for the final end user.

I suggest you to read that page.
http://doc.locomotivecms.com/guides/get-started/requirements
and this one too
http://www.locomotivecms.com/tour

Our message is still not clear on our official website but believe me, we are working to make it better.

Hope it will help you !

Didier

Comment: Thanks Didier. I still don't feel clear at all as to how to set it up on my own server (I can't use Heroku because it needs to be internal to our firewall), but I've switched to using another CMS this time, so it's no problem! Thanks anyway - I appreciate you taking the time to reply.